# Shrink a number x times to a value

Tags: c#, math

Good morning,

I create an application that should display a stack of pancakes, the bigger at the bottom, then the higher it goes the smaller the pancakes become.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
        int width = 930;

        List<Grid> crêpes = new List<Grid>();

        // Pour chaque crêpe
        for (int i = nbCrêpe; i >= 1; i--)
        {

            Grid crêpe = new Grid // Création de la crêpe
            {
                Width = width, 
            };

            // Taille en longueur de la crêpe qui diminue de plus en plus
            width -= 20 ;

            crêpes.Add(crêpe);
        }
```

As you can see, since I didn't solve my problem, I just decreased the length of each pancake by 20.

But I would like the first pancake to be at the basic size (930 as in my code) and then shrink so that at the end I have a pancake that goes from 930 to 100 for example.

ps : "nbCrêpe" is the number of crepe to create.

If you have a solution to my problem, I'll take it.
Thanks :)

Comment: So you have `930-100` pixels of shrinkwidth and have to do that over `nbCrêpe` (ungarian notations AND accents? urghhh) crepes ... how much do you need to reduce your average crepe by?

Comment: That stack of pancakes will look awkward in the end, much like a cone. Why would someone make pancakes smaller just to stack them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the crapes to change by the same size every time, you'll need to change your variables from *int* to *double*.

And the solutions is:

```
           int nbCrêpe = 50;

        double startWidth = 930;
        double endWidth = 100;

        List<Grid> crêpes = new List<Grid>();

        // By how mach you change each crêpe
        double changeWidth = (startWidth - endWidth) / (nbCrêpe - 1);

        // Pour chaque crêpe
        for (int i = nbCrêpe; i >= 1; i--)
        {

            Grid crêpe = new Grid // Création de la crêpe
            {
                Width = startWidth,
            };

            // Taille en longueur de la crêpe qui diminue de plus en plus
            startWidth -= changeWidth;

            crêpes.Add(crêpe);
        }
```

The crêpes width are:

```
930, 913.0612244897959, 896.1224489795918, 879.1836734693877, 862.2448979591836, 845.3061224489795, 828.3673469387754, 811.4285714285713, 794.4897959183672, 777.5510204081631, 760.612244897959, 743.673469387755, 726.7346938775509, 709.7959183673468, 692.8571428571427, 675.9183673469386, 658.9795918367345, 642.0408163265304, 625.1020408163263, 608.1632653061222, 591.2244897959181, 574.285714285714, 557.3469387755099, 540.4081632653058, 523.4693877551017, 506.5306122448976, 489.5918367346935, 472.6530612244894, 455.7142857142853, 438.77551020408123, 421.83673469387713, 404.89795918367304, 387.95918367346894, 371.02040816326485, 354.08163265306075, 337.14285714285666, 320.20408163265256, 303.26530612244846, 286.32653061224437, 269.3877551020403, 252.44897959183618, 235.51020408163208, 218.571428571428, 201.6326530612239, 184.6938775510198, 167.7551020408157, 150.8163265306116, 133.8775510204075, 116.93877551020343, 99.99999999999935,
```

If you don't want to use *double* you can use this solution:

```
int nbCrêpe = 50;

        int startWidth = 930;
        int endWidth = 100;

        List<Grid> crêpes = new List<Grid>();

        // By how mach you change each crêpe
        int changeWidth = (startWidth - endWidth) / (nbCrêpe - 1);

        // Pour chaque crêpe
        for (int i = nbCrêpe; i >= 2; i--)
        {

            Grid crêpe = new Grid // Création de la crêpe
            {
                Width = startWidth,
            };

            // Taille en longueur de la crêpe qui diminue de plus en plus
            startWidth -= changeWidth;

            crêpes.Add(crêpe);
        }

        // Adding the last crêpe

        Grid lastCrêpe = new Grid // Création de la crêpe
        {
            Width = endWidth,
        };

        crêpes.Add(lastCrêpe);
```

The output is:

```
930, 914, 898, 882, 866, 850, 834, 818, 802, 786, 770, 754, 738, 722, 706, 690, 674, 658, 642, 626, 610, 594, 578, 562, 546, 530, 514, 498, 482, 466, 450, 434, 418, 402, 386, 370, 354, 338, 322, 306, 290, 274, 258, 242, 226, 210, 194, 178, 162, 100,
```

Answer (score 1):

just a classic problem of math:

```
int initialwidth = 930;
int finalwdidth = 100;
int nbCrepe = asyouwant;

List<Grid> crêpes = new List<Grid>();

    // Pour chaque crêpe
    for (int i = 0; i < nbCrepe; i++)
    {

        Grid crêpe = new Grid // Création de la crêpe
        {
            Width = initialwidth - ((initialwidth - finalwidth) * i / (nbCrepes - 1)); 
        };

        // Taille en longueur de la crêpe qui diminue de plus en plus

        crêpes.Add(crêpe);
    }
```